# get the value of dynamically created textboxes within PlaceHolder

Tags: c#, sql, stored-procedures, dynamically-generated

I have dynamically created a table in c# that has 2 columns: 1st column fetches its data using SqlDataReader out of stored procedure and the 2nd is made of textboxes and is exactly as long as the 1st column. at the end the table is placed within a placeholder and displayed on the UI.
the idea behind it do build a form and after completing it, there is button that has to get the values out of every text box and save that in a table on database.

```
HtmlTableRow row;
HtmlTableCell cell;
HtmlTableCell celltf;
TextBox text;

protected void createTables(){
HtmlTable dataTable = new HtmlTable();
HtmlTableRow header = new HtmlTableRow();

    while (rdr.Read())
    {
        row = new HtmlTableRow();

        for (int j = 0; j < rdr.FieldCount; j++)
        {
            cell = new HtmlTableCell();
            cell.InnerText = (rdr.GetValue(j)).ToString();

            celltf = new HtmlTableCell();
            text = new TextBox();
            celltf.Controls.Add(text);

            row.Cells.Add(cell);
            row.Cells.Add(celltf);
        }
        dataTable.Rows.Add(row);
    }
    dataTable.DataBind();
}
```

What is the best way to get the values out of every textbox, when the button is clicked? As the Button_clicked() is a separate function.

Answer (score 0):

I can't promise this works like: http://lukieb.blogspot.co.uk/2009/03/event-handlers-with-dynamic-controls.html because it is slightly different but if you always re-create the same number of controls in page_load, I think the form will correctly set all their values when you do a postback to the event handler. You should then be able to do a simple set of foreach calls on the table. Presumably your table is declared on the aspx page or otherwise added to the page controls rather than just being created locally?